# Hidden Markov Model Materials

Tags: probability

Please i need materials that i get online that would explain hidden markov model thoroughly,the ones am getting are too advanced.I am working on hidden markov model application to rainfall.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this series of lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_y5hx_ySCg&list=PLix7MmR3doRo3NGNzrq48FItR3TDyuLCo) out. It covers basics, intuition and details in quite a beginner-friendly manner. The series is based on [this paper](https://web.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf).